# Android: OnClickListener OnClick event in different class

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener

I want to set OnClick event inside another class that can be used by 2 different class (Activity A and Activity B)

Example:

Activity A

```
public class A extends Activity {

    String sample = "Sample text";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textview);
        findViewById(R.id.btn_sampleA).setOnClickListener(new C());

    }
}
```

Activity B

```
public class B extends Activity {

    String sample = "Sample text";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);

        TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textview);
        findViewById(R.id.btn_sampleB).setOnClickListener(new C());

    }
}
```

Activity C where onClick event placed

```
public class C implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_sampleA:
            textview.setText(sample);
            break;
        case R.id.btn_sampleB:
            textview.setText(sample);
            break;
    }
}
```

Tried by myself but not working, so is that possible doing like that? Or there's another way that can be used?

Comment: You should pas the correct textview in the constructor of C, the id's will be resolved without a problem but the reference to textview is a problem. If C is a innner class of activity C then you should make that inner class static

Comment: Still don't get what do you mean. If possible could you please provide a sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the constructor of class `C` to take a TextView as an argument:

```
public class C implements OnClickListener {
TextView mTextView;    

public C (TextView text){
    mTextView = text;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn_sampleA:
        mTextView.setText(sample);
        break;
    case R.id.btn_sampleB:
        mTextView.setText(sample);
        break;
}
}
```

Then call instantiate C like this:

```
findViewById(R.id.btn_sampleA).setOnClickListener(new C(textView));
```

Comment: Thats working but only after declarate String sample = "sample"; inside activity C. Thanks btw I got it

Comment: Please make inner classes static!

Comment: This is not necessarily an inner class.

Comment: Indeed your are right, but if you take a look at the question then it is